# How do I change the classic asp start page from with in IIS directly

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am changing some markup and need to make another classic asp page as the start up page from with in IIS. How do I change the classic asp start page from IIS directly?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the default document is the starting page for your application.  The following directions will help you navigate to the appropriate section within IIS. For this example, Windows 2012 will be used.

This is how you update the default document from within IIS.

**Select the appropriate site or application**

[image]

---

**Click "Default Document"**

[image]

---

**Add your Default document and move it to the top of the list using the arrows on the right.**

[image]

Comment: Hi @SteveHoldorf if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Good answer but the OP doesn't specify which version of IIS they are using, so a bit of a presumption being made. This will only work for IIS 7 and above.

Comment: @SteveHoldorf As the previous poster mentioned, the above instructions support IIS 7 or higher.  The OS bundled with IIS 6 was Windows 2003 and this version will reach its End of Life (aka EOL)  on 7/14/2015 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/.